# Erro por causa desconhecida: "SyntaxError: invalid range in character class"

Tags: html, string, regex, firebug

## Situação:

Tenho uma página que contém um `<iframe>` de outra, nesta outra página, tenho um simples elemento HTML `input`:

```html
<input type="text" required="" pattern="[a-Z]{2,35}" tabindex="6" name="edtCidade" id="edtCidade">
```

Tenho certeza e me certifiquei que não há nenhum tipo de evento atribuído à ele ou código alterando suas propriedades.

Porém, toda vez que eu digito, qualquer tecla, pode ser número, pode ser letra, qualquer coisa, à cada vez que eu digito me gera este erro no console:

> SyntaxError: invalid range in character class

## Exemplo:

Se eu digitar "az123" eu vou ter 5 erros de `SyntaxError` no console de meu navegador.

## Importante:

**Este erro não me causa nenhum problema, ele é insignificante porém está me incomodando, e gostaria de saber a origem dele.**

## Pergunta:

Como resolver este erro? Porque ele é ocasionado? Gostaria de uma explicação detalhada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro é associado à expressões regulares, sendo causado pelo range `a-Z` (`a` minúscula e `Z` maiúsculo) no atributo `pattern`.

Como o atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) é um elemento do `input` incluído no **HTML5**, a expressão será executada mesmo sem nenhum plugin ou evento adicional.

Para aceitar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, use `[a-zA-Z]`, pois parece não haver uma forma de tornar o padrão *case insensitive*.

**Nota**: no Chrome não ocorre essa exceção, ele apenas ignora a validação. Imagino, então, que você esteja usando o Firefox. :)

#### [Demo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCCcD/1/)

Answer (score 4):

As listas em expressões regulares são baseadas na tabela ASCII (http://www.asciitable.com/). Segundo essa tabela, `a` é o caractere de número 97 e `Z` é o caractere de número 90 – por causa disso, não faz sentido você escrever uma lista que diz "aqui são válidos todos os caracteres entre 97 e 90" (o primeiro número deve ser menor do que o segundo).

O comum é fazer `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` ou, simplesmente, `\w+`. Para validar apenas números use `[0-9]+`, ou `\d+`.

Comment: Só pra complementar o `\w` pega `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: É verdade, já corrigi. Obrigado!

Comment: O padrão correto a ser utilizado no lugar do `[a-Z]{2,35}` inválido seria `[A-z]{2,35}` correspondente, na tabela ASCII, ao intervalo 65 à 122. No entanto, como já dizia o Mestre Aurélio: `Não use o intervalo A-z, prefira A-Za-z`, isso porque esse intervalo abrange seis outros caracteres, a saber: [ \ ] ^ _ ` os quais sem a devido cautela podem ser um problema para a Aplicação.

Answer (score 4):

É um erro de expressão regular.

```
[a-Z]{2,35} não é vlálido  
Use [a-zA-Z]{2,35}
```

Tente usar

```
<input type="text" required="" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,35}" tabindex="6" name="edtCidade" id="edtCidade">
```